retry Laravel http response 200 with error
I connect to an API that possibly returns status 200 but with errors in the response JSON.
I would like to retry if the error is not a client error of if the above occurs.
Using the ->retry() closure for that.
What I tried:
$response = Http::acceptJson()
->retry([100,200], when: function($exception, $request) {
  if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException) {
      return !$exception->response->clientError();
  }

  if ($exception instanceOf \Illuminate\Http\Client\Response) {
    $response = $exception;
    if ($response->ok() && fluent($response->json())->collect('errors')->pluck('message')->contains('error but retry')) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
})
->get('http://localhost:3001/test')

My mocked API returns in sequence:

502 bad gateway
200 {"errors": [{"message": "error but retry"}]}
200 {"data": [{"one": 1}]}
401 unauthorized

When running the above code it indeed retries for 502 and stops for 401.
But it does not retry for the 200 with errors.
The closure does not seem to be called if there is no exception.
How can I retry if the response is 200 but it contains a specific error.

Ended up using:
$response = retry([300,400], function() {
  $response = Http::acceptJson()
    ->retry([100,200],
      when: fn($exception, $request) => 
        !$exception->response?->clientError()
    )
    ->get('http://localhost:3001/test')

    if (fluent($response->json())
      ->collect('errors')->pluck('message')->contains('error but retry')
    ) {
      throw new \Exception('error that we want to retry');
    }

  return $response;
},
  when: fn($exception) => 
    !$exception->response?->clientError()
);

